# Почему не работает перетаскивание в android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Только создал новый проект. И заметил, что стандартные элементы не высвечиваются. Что делать?

Вот фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Возможные** способы решения данной проблемы:

- Попробуйте перезапустить студию.
- Build > Clean Project.
- Если у Вас маломощный компьютер - подождите.

Comment: На удивление второе помогло) Вот только не пойму, я добавил кнопку и вылезает  какое-то предупреждение. В вопросе фото.

Comment: Это, скорее, совет, к которому очень желательно прислушаться. В директории ресурсов есть каталог `values`, а в нем файл `strings.xml`. В него должен добавляться весь текст, который виден пользователю в приложении,- в вашем случае - текст кнопки. Обращаться к конкретной строке нужно так `@string/your_key` или так `R.string.your_key`. Например, если Вы решите внедрить поддержку еще одного языка, достаточно создать дополнительный файл `strings.xml` с выбором нужного языка и перевести все строки - android автоматически выберет нужный. Игнорирование не влияет на работу приложения.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)